# How to add "multiple" attribute to dynamic generated Input File?

Tags: javascript, input, attributes

I need to add `multiple` attribute to input type `file` but I don't know how to do it.

Below My code:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "file";
input.id = "files" + af;
input.name = "imgs[]";
input.className = "upload";
```

But I need the input to have `multiple` atribute.

Comment: Use this: `input.setAttribute('multiple','');`

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you @behzadbesharati

Answer (score 7):

Just use `setAttribute()` function like below example :

```js
 var af = 1;
var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type","file");
  input.setAttribute("id" ,"files" + af);
  input.setAttribute("name","imgs[]");
  input.setAttribute("multiple","");
  input.className = "upload";
          
  console.log(input);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. With your code I get the same result " <input type="file" id="files1" name="imgs[]" class="upload"> " but I need something like this " <input type="file" id="files1" name="imgs[]" class="upload" multiple> ". With the "multiple" attribute.

Comment: that's what I've mentiend in answer , you can do set all default attribu using this last

Answer (score 1):

```
input.setAttribute('multiple','');
```

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers fully explain this, though they are somewhat correct.  The problem is that the 'multiple' attribute must be set AFTER adding the element to the DOM.  I'm not sure why it works this way, but I could not get this to work until I changed the order of execution.  Here is how it should look:

```
const fileElement = document.createElement("input");
fileElement.type = 'file';
document.body.appendChild(fileElement);
fileElement.setAttribute('multiple', '');
```

In my case, I have made this element hidden (with additional code), so I just attached it to the body.  You'll want to attach it to a parent element that makes more sense if you are displaying this element.